# how to throw original exception when one rest api call another api

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, controller, resttemplate

There are 2(A and B) REST API in my controller. A can call B by RestTemplate.
Both A and B throw Exception, now A receieved a request, then call B and B throw an Exception, but I only get 500 status code, no exception details returned.

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate internalRestRouter;

@PostMapping("/A")
public Object handleACommand(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) throws CliException {
    return internalRestRouter.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/B", null, Object.class);
}

@PostMapping("/B")
public Object handleBCommand() throws CliException {
    throw new CliException("B Exception details");
}
```

How can I get Exception details threw by B when I call A?

Comment: did 'B' added the exception details in its response body (httpResponse.setEntity(...)) ?
did 'A' tried to extract the entity from B's response?

Comment: @ruhul No explict response body wrapper in my code. Only return json result if it's ok or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use ControllerAdvice to process both exception.

Comment: Can you please add more details/code to elaborate your answer.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f

Answer (score 0):

> **@Wd Ly** suggestion i supported
>
> Writing a controller advice Developers tested out many ways to make a
>   controller advice class work. After hard work, they found the
>   following points to take into account:
>
> Create your own exception classes. Despite Spring provides many
>   classes that **represent common exceptions in an application**, it is
>   better practice to write your own or extending those existing. One
>   controller advice class per application. *It is a good idea to have all
>   exception handlers in a single class instead of annotating multiple*
>   ones with **@ControllerAdvice**. Write a **handleException method**. This one
>   is meant to be annotated with **@ExceptionHandler** and will handle all
>   exceptions declared in it and then will delegate to a specific handler
>   method. Add one method handler per exception. Imagine you want to
>   handle a **UserNotFoundException**, then create a
>   **handleUserNotFoundException**. Create a method that sends the response
>   to the user. Handler methods are meant to do the logic to treat a
>   given exception, then they will call the method that sends the
>   respond. This method will receive a list of errors as body and the
>   specific HTTP status.

```
@ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
        /** Provides handling for exceptions throughout this service. */
        @ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class, ContentNotAllowedException.class })
        public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

            if (ex instanceof UserNotFoundException) {
                HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
                UserNotFoundException unfe = (UserNotFoundException) ex;

                return handleUserNotFoundException(unfe, headers, status, request);
            } else if (ex instanceof ContentNotAllowedException) {
                HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                ContentNotAllowedException cnae = (ContentNotAllowedException) ex;

                return handleContentNotAllowedException(cnae, headers, status, request);
            } else {
                HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, status, request);
            }
        }

        /** Customize the response for UserNotFoundException. */
        protected ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleUserNotFoundException(UserNotFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
            List<String> errors = Collections.singletonList(ex.getMessage());
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ApiError(errors), headers, status, request);
        }

        /** Customize the response for ContentNotAllowedException. */
        protected ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleContentNotAllowedException(ContentNotAllowedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
            List<String> errorMessages = ex.getErrors()
                    .stream()
                    .map(contentError -> contentError.getObjectName() + " " + contentError.getDefaultMessage())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ApiError(errorMessages), headers, status, request);
        }

        /** A single place to customize the response body of all Exception types. */
        protected ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, ApiError body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
            if (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(status)) {
                request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE, ex, WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
        }
    }
```